# Need root password change

Tags: mysql, passwords

Can't change root password for mysql (mariadb).

I have already tried:
stop service, start it with:
`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
Tried various update lines from the web including:
`update user set password=PASSWORD('newpassword') where user='root';` and `update user set authentication_string=password('newpassword') where user='root';`
and `update user set password=PASSWORD('newpassword') where user='root';` and `update user set password=('newpassword') where user='root;` and after each of these: `flush privileges;`

no code

The root password doesn't work no matter what I try. How can it *actually* be changed?

Comment: what mysql version?

Comment: there's official documentation you can use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html rather than various web items. Adjust for your server version.

Answer (score 1):

In your localhost PHPMyAdmin, go to `Privileges -> edit privileges ->change password`.